# How to get access to heroku config variables in C# code (asp.net)?

Tags: c#, heroku, config

I deployed my asp.net application with unhidden secret token. I will add heroku config variable 'token=***' but i don't know how to access to it in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config variables that are set in Heroku's settings are provided to your website application as environment variables.

> Config vars are exposed to your app’s code as environment variables. For example, in Node.js you can access your app’s DATABASE_URL config var with process.env.DATABASE_URL.
>
> Source: [Accessing config var values from code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#accessing-config-var-values-from-code)

So in ASP.NET, if `FOO` is the name of your config var, it can be accessed like this:

```cs
var fooVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FOO");
```

See [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more information on accessing environment variables.